# Insert code template in eclipse on mac os x (ctrl-space not working)

Tags: eclipse, macos

How can insert code template in eclipse on mac os x?

ctrl-space is not working :(

Comment: Was also a bug in OpenJDK : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8272790 - fixed Temurin 11.0.13+8

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> can be intercepted by Spotlight (depending on its configuration)

Go into:

```
System Preferences -> Spotlight
```

At the bottom, change the Spotlight menu shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Espace</kbd>) in any other shortcut like:

<kbd>(cmd) ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>espace</kbd>

[image: http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT2531/HT2531---fr.png]

Comment: Many thanks.
I have installed Dreamweaver 5.5 the the Zend Studio and Komodo IDE and same problem in all of them.
Then I understood it's might be a Mac keyboard shortcut but since I use VMWare I didn't knew that the spotlight is opened at the background.

Comment: Might be better to change Eclipse's shortcut than Mac's.
And btw, Eclipse Mac is by defaut Ctrl+. (control+dot).

Comment: @DavidTorres Strange: maybe ask a new question specific for VSCode? (this one was, 7 years ago, for Eclipse)

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old post, but I didn't find much else when searching for this problem.

In my case (Yosemite - 10.10.5), I found that

```
System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Input Sources
```

was set to capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: For some reason the Input Sources pane wasn't showing in shortcuts. I had to create another input source, then it'd show

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `cmd+space` and `option+space`? Also you should be able to change this key sequence by going to Eclipse > Preferences > General > Keys

Answer (score 2):

If you have emacs-bindings set up in eclipse, then the key is "option-/", not ctrl-space.

Answer (score 1):

On Eclipse Oxygen, on MacOS Sierra the shortcut is ctrl-.